# Story-identification : Movie with brother and sister who had some sort of powers end up on a farm?

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

There was a movie that was maybe aired on Disney or ABC family with two kids, a brother and sister, who had some sort of special abilities. I don't recall the abilities all too well but they end up on a farm.

At the end they are trying to get away from some evil guy who is trying to take advantage of their powers.

A spaceship randomly shows up at the end of the movie and they decide to leave earth. They ask a women who they befriend to come along.

She says to them "somebody has to stay to tell the story".

If anybody remembers the name of this movie please let me know.

Comment: Can you recall any other details? While this may be enough to identify it, some additional details might really help.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like the 1975 Disney film Escape To Witch Mountain. From IMDB:

> Tony (Ike Eisenmann) and Tia Malone (Kim Richards) are two orphaned siblings with extraordinary psychic powers. When their abilities attract the attention of a cruel millionaire, Aristotle Bolt (Ray Milland), he kidnaps them with plans to exploit their powers for financial gain. Tony and Tia escape, and with the help of Jason O'Day (Eddie Albert), a bitter widower camping in a nearby Winnebago, they attempt to elude Bolt and begin to discover their otherworldly origins.

Comment: That was my thought then, but the last part with the woman and her quote don't match up.

Comment: Maybe she's in [this remake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_to_Witch_Mountain_(1995_film)) or else [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_to_Witch_Mountain) .

Comment: There is i think a woman or maybe a man with long hair who is invited to go with them but they refuse right at the end - the Jason O'day is the one